# Openstack Keystone Authentication failure

Tags: openstack, openstack-keystone

I am new to Openstack. I installed Openstack using Packstack in my CentOS machine. When I try to login using the default `keystone_admin` credentials, it showed a server error.

Here is my `keystone.log` file. Can somebody help?

```
2020-05-07 03:13:57.097 2303 WARNING keystone.server.flask.application [req-8c75dc88-73f3-4605-8a6b-3ba515d9fd84 3a3280ddae08412ab1145c193b587161 - - default -] Authorization failed. The request you have made requires authentication. from 192.168.225.30: Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication.
2020-05-07 03:13:57.235 2300 WARNING keystone.common.rbac_enforcer.enforcer [req-d1a5e980-617f-48d4-8322-40b0aa068140 3a3280ddae08412ab1145c193b587161 - - default -] Deprecated policy rules found. Use oslopolicy-policy-generator and oslopolicy-policy-upgrade to detect and resolve deprecated policies in your configuration.
```

[image]

[Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhG3v.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to find any rc files in your /root folder.

the file name is similar with openrc or adminrc

$ .openrc

$ try some openstack command

and it will succeed.